# netsh not scanning for new networks while connected

Tags: javascript, node.js, wifi, kiosk, netsh

OK, so, I am building a kiosk system. I am using netsh to scan for wifi networks and to connect to them. That works fine. What my problem is is that while the device (problem present in portable devices, microsoft surface) is connected to a WiFi network and a new network pops up, it does not see the new network until the wifi icon in the task bar is clicked, which seems to initiate a scan somehow. The backend of my application is Node.js, if that helps. I'm thinking it may be an issue with certain power saving features. Any ideas anyone about how I can initiate a scan through the command line or maybe get windows to see all the new networks without having to click the icon in the taskbar?

The command I am using with netsh is "netsh wlan show networks".

Thanks